# Tick inside circle

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to create tick Inside filled circle.

I did following but, doesn't looks perfect.

```html
<svg height=10 viewBox="0 0 10 10" width=10>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#22AE73" stroke-width="1"></g>
    <circle cx=5 cy=5 fill='#29AB87' r=5 />
    <polyline stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2" points="2.5,5.8 4.7,7.9 9.2,2.4 " />
</svg>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change the size of the surface where you are setting this image. This is a SVG image so it will be big as you can without stretching.

Comment: @PratikButani I changed my question. Even this doesn't looks perfect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your points are reaching the `10 10` part of your viewbox, hence it doesn't fit. You could change your points to lower values.

Alternatively, here's an svg that might work for you that is path based

```html
<svg width="10px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="tick">
                <circle id="Oval" fill="#349006" cx="5" cy="5" r="5"></circle>
                <path d="M7.26241838,2.25 L8.35843389,3.34601551 L3.9390165,7.76543289 L3.937,7.763 L3.93041937,7.77093389 L1.65,5.49051452 L2.74601551,4.39449901 L3.932,5.58 L7.26241838,2.25 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```